# suse yast nothing provides .so needed by, building from source

Tags: rpm, dependencies, suse

I have some software provided as an x8-64.rpm.  The one specifically giving me a problem let's call it `MYSoftwareRPM.x86_64`.

Using Yast-Software Manager it tells me `nothing provides libreadline.so.6()(64bit) needed by MySoftwareRPM.x86_64`

I am running SLES 11.4 x86-64 and that has libreadline5.  If I access the SLES_12.2.iso repository I can see readline-6.3 and if I choose that I get a 100+ dependency problems basically uninstalling SLES version 11.4 and giving me the impression if I want readline6 I need to be running SLES 12.2.

I was able to download `readline-6.3.tar.gz` and successfully build it via  `configure --prefix=/usr/local/readline-6.3; make all; make install`

Whether this is correct or not, I manually did

```
ln -s /usr/local/readline-6.3/lib/libreadline.so.6 /lib64/libreadline.so.6
ln -s /usr/local/readline-6.3/lib/libreadline.so.6 /lib/libreadline.so.6
ln -s /usr/local/readline-6.3/lib/libreadline.so.6 /usr/lib64/libreadline.so.6
ln -s /usr/local/readline-6.3/lib/libreadline.so.6 /usr/lib/libreadline.so.6
```

My questions are

1. in such a scenario what is the best way to install `MySoftwareRPM.x86_64?
2. is there a way to do it so the Yast Software Manager is happy and does not report any dependency problems?
3. If I neglect the dependency issue with Yast Software Manager or manually install via `rpm -ivh MySoftwareRPM.x64_64` and force it, then provided the libreadline.so.6 is available will MySoftwareRPM.x86_64 work when executed?
4. if doing #3 then is all that's needed `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LIBRARY_PATH}:/usr/local/readline-6.3/lib` ?

Answer (score 0):

You are better off using rpm as root:

```
rpm -i --nodeps --nosignature MySoftwareRPM.x86_64.rpm
```

as for readline6, better run

```
configure && make install && ldconfig
```

then it will be in `/usr/local` and the system will find it. No need to alter `ld.so.conf`.